# Migrating from Weblogic to WAS8.0

Tags: servlets, websphere, weblogic, servlet-filters

We had two jar files - weblogic.jar and weblogic-binding.jar 
Now as we are moving to WAS8.0, i removed these two files from the project.
(After removing the files, i make sure that javax.servlet api is available to my project from Websphere). 
From then, I am getting below exception:

```
[8/15/13 15:21:34:180 EDT] 00000016 ExceptionHand E dcf.ess.frameworks.exception.ProgramLogicException logException Unhandled Exception caught and new ProgramLogic exception thrown. - UnavailableException: null Code:  P3003FEXS01 ID:dd953aa2-e52e-49f0-95ed-33c121a2bdfd
                                 dcf.ess.frameworks.exception.ProgramLogicException: UnavailableException: null
    at dcf.ess.frameworks.exception.ExceptionHandler.findRootException(ExceptionHandler.java:50)
    at dcf.ess.frameworks.exception.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:31)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.frameworks.presentation.SessionFilter.redirectToErrorPage(SessionFilter.java:92)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.frameworks.presentation.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:54)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.frameworks.presentation.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:28)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:919)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:883)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1659)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1648)
Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:482)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:449)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.frameworks.presentation.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:46)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: It is impossible to solve this without looking into your code. What is `P3003FEXS01`?

Comment: Wrapped exception is `javax.servlet.UnavailableException`, which suggests something in your servlets or filters depends on the jars you removed. Did you check logs/ffdc folder? there may be additional information there. You may also check server during startup, there may be some configuration problems reported, well before the servlet is used.

Answer (score 0):

What is "dcf.ess.frameworks"?

Did you recompile the application or you simply removed the jar file from the ear ?

Comment: No, i recompiled and deployed again. dcf.ess.frameworks is one of the package we are using in our project.

Comment: do you hace the code of dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.frameworks.presentation.SessionFilter?